# GDX-SQLite android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, libgdx, cursor

I work in Android Studio with [libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) and [gdx-sqlite](https://github.com/mrafayaleem/gdx-sqlite). I want a simple query from my database with the following code.

```
 try {
        cursorSettings = dbHandler.rawQuery("SELECT "+COLUMN_SETTING+" FROM "+TABLE_SETTINGS+" WHERE "+COLUMN_SETTINGSID+" =13");
        System.out.println(cursorSettings.getLong(0));
    } catch (SQLiteGdxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Desktop-Version works without problems, but in the android version I get the following error:

```
05-25 10:21:47.341 11978-12232/ch.shuttering.rapporte E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 82275
    Process: ch.shuttering.rapporte, PID: 11978
    android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:74)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.sqlite.android.AndroidCursor.getLong(AndroidCursor.java:61)
        at ch.shuttering.rapporte.Manager.SQLiteManager.SaveMangerSQLite.creatSQLiteSettings(SaveMangerSQLite.java:295)
        at ch.shuttering.rapporte.RapporteMain.create(RapporteMain.java:66)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:311)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1546)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1262)
```

So every time I make a getXXX () query from the cursor I get an error, but if I now use the following code:

```
 try {
        cursorSettings = dbHandler.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_SETTINGS);
    } catch (SQLiteGdxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (cursorSettings.next()) {
        Gdx.app.log("FromDb", String.valueOf(cursorSettings.getString(1)));
    }
```

I have a correct output with all data.
Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the problem by myself, that was the code in the Android class

```
@Override
        public long getLong (int columnIndex) {
            try { 
                return cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                Gdx.app.log(DatabaseFactory.ERROR_TAG, "There was an error in getting the long", e);
                throw new SQLiteGdxRuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

The problem is that in android the cursor points to -1 so it must first be set to the correct position, the following code solves the problem

```
@Override
    public long getLong (int columnIndex) {
        try {
           cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Gdx.app.log(DatabaseFactory.ERROR_TAG, "There was an error in getting the long", e);
            throw new SQLiteGdxRuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

You can found this code in the library gdx-sqlite-android.jar in the class AndroidCursor.

I hope the solution helps someone.